# Is there any way of extracting a shared secret from a PBK file or a similar artefact from a Windows 7 installation?

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, vpn, ipsec

My company's laptop comes with preconfigured VPN connections to access the company's network.
The default setup of the laptop is a bit outdated to say the least and I was wondering if in some cases I would be able to use my development laptop to access the same network, but in order to do that I need to go through our VPN.
My development laptop happens to be a Mac and the only piece of information I am missing is the shared secret which, paradoxically is not really shared (as I am using it but I don't know it).

Are shared secrets stored somehow in PBK files or somewhere else in the system?
With PCF files (for Cisco VPN connections) it is easy extracting the shared secret, so somehow I am hoping for the best.

Cheers.

Comment: Why not ask your company IT to give you the shared secret, and/or have them help you get it set up properly?  (You may want to do that BEFORE trying to hook an unknown computer to their network.)

Comment: Even if this works, chances are your IT guys will be quite irate at you for bringing in a system that's not vetted by them. Its all fun and games, until something behaves inappropriately and stuff breaks. You *really* ought to talk to your company IT staff about this.